# jq - multiple if

Tags: json, jq

input json file:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1e9b2215-9efd-67cc-9113-1e21c74f09d3",
    "login": "u0159",
    "name": "Pat ABC",
    "role": "User",
    "groups": null,
    "disabled": false,
    "lLoginTime": 1567158950468,
    "lLoginFrom": "192.168.100.11"
  },
  {
    "id": "1e9b2215-9efd-67cc-9113-2b21c74f09d3",
    "login": "u0154",
    "name": "Roman ABC",
    "role": "User",
    "groups": [
      {
        "id": "1e8dc82a-596f-623c-8bc5-100000000000",
        "name": "Default ABC"
      },
      {
        "id": "1e99833f-9876-65d0-9d24-237228b9d9e0",
        "name": "AGE"
      }
    ],
    "disabled": false,
    "lLoginTime": 1567158950468,
    "lLoginFrom": "192.168.100.11"
  },
  {
    "id": "1e9b2215-9c2b-64f4-a0f1-47abdab7ae5f",
    "login": "u0155",
    "name": "Tomas CDE",
    "role": "User",
    "groups": [
      {
        "id": "1e8dc82a-596f-623c-8bc5-100000000000",
        "name": "ZZZ"
      },
      {
        "id": "1e8dc82a-596f-623c-8bc5-100000000000",
        "name": "Default ABC"
      },
      {
        "id": "1e99234f-9876-65d0-9d24-534528b9d9e0",
        "name": "NTE"
      }
    ],
    "disabled": false,
    "lLoginTime": 1566302653093,
    "lLoginFrom": "192.168.100.16"
  }
]
```

I want to extend following filter:

```
$ jq -r '.[]|[.id, .login, ( if .groups == null then "n/a" else ([.groups[].name]|join("|")) end )]|@tsv' /tmp/test__
1e9b2215-9efd-67cc-9113-1e21c74f09d3    u0159   n/a
1e9b2215-9efd-67cc-9113-2b21c74f09d3    u0154   Default ABC|AGE
1e9b2215-9c2b-64f4-a0f1-47abdab7ae5f    u0155   ZZZ|Default ABC|NTE
```

to rid of all "Default ABC" from the list of groups separated by | on output

I tried with additional if but it fails with error:

```
$ jq -r '.[]|[.id, .login, ( if .groups == null then "n/a" else ( if .groups[].name != "Default ABC" then [.groups[].name]|join("|")) end ) end )]|@tsv' /tmp/test__
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected ')' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
```

appreciate any hint...

expected output for the sample json is:

```
1e9b2215-9efd-67cc-9113-1e21c74f09d3    u0159   n/a
1e9b2215-9efd-67cc-9113-2b21c74f09d3    u0154   AGE
1e9b2215-9c2b-64f4-a0f1-47abdab7ae5f    u0155   ZZZ|NTE
```

Update: Solution provided by oliv:

```
$ jq -r '.[]|[.id,.login,if .groups then (.groups|map(select(.name != "Default ABC").name)|join("|")) else "n/a" end]|@tsv' /tmp/test__
1e9b2215-9efd-67cc-9113-1e21c74f09d3    u0159   n/a
1e9b2215-9efd-67cc-9113-2b21c74f09d3    u0154   AGE
1e9b2215-9c2b-64f4-a0f1-47abdab7ae5f    u0155   ZZZ|NTE
```

Comment: I think you want `elif` but I can't make a fixed version because 1) every if-then-else *must* include the else branch, and I don't know what to put in it, and 2) I'm not sure what you actually want to do about "Default ABC", which would be the else case, anyway - at the moment all the items would be repeated once for each other item (try `if .groups == null then "n/a" elif .groups[].name != "Default ABC" then [.groups[].name]|join("|") else "?????" end` and see the output).

Comment: I need to ignore all occurrences of "Default ABC". Of course I could process the first filter output via sed or tr to rid of "Default ABC", but I thought maybe it can be handled directly in jq filter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that if `groups` exists, it's an array, you could filter out the unwanted `name` using `select`:

```
<file jq -r '.[]|[.id,.login,if .groups then (.groups|map(select(.name != "Default ABC").name)|join("|")) else "n/a" end]|@tsv'
```